# How Can We Made Adding, Dividing Process on Number-Phase Situations?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

How we made this calculations? I didn't found any topic for that. Should i use calculator for that?

$1\angle0^{\circ}+(0.1)(1\angle-25.8^{\circ})+j(0.9)(1\angle-25.8^{\circ})$

$(\frac{11,710\angle90^{\circ}-(6298\angle0^{\circ})}{0.072\angle{j}0.648})$

Comment: Please don't use pictures.
Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Dietrich Burde but i first time saw '<' this operator with straight line. So i don't know how can i add.

Comment: It is "\angle" in MathJax. Look here: $\angle$. So $1\angle 0^{\circ}$.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde i tried my best. But i couldn't do 'o' symbol on angles :(.

Comment: For degree symbol use `^{\circ}`

Comment: @Yooo Thanks. I hope someone will help even question has -2 rating (:.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the topic *Number-Phase Situations*.  So, the answer to the following question may already be known by other MathSE reviewers.  What is the significance of (for example) the expression $$11,710 \angle 90^\circ ~?$$  It looks like you are taking a *scalar*, $~11,710~$ and mulitplying it by an angle.  What is the significance of that computation?

Comment: Also, for an explanation of why your posting is being downvoted, and what you might do, going forward, for this or your future MathSE postings, see [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: I think what the OP is trying to do is operations for electrical engineering, where complex numbers are converted to polar form (i.e. $r \angle \theta$), but there are limitations on what operations you can perform.  For example, you cannot add or subtract two numbers in polar form; you must convert to rectangular (i.e $a+bi$ form) to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint for Question $1$:**

You can factor out $1 \angle -25.8°$, but you either (a) have to convert $1 + j0.9$ to polar form or $1 \angle -25.8°$ to rectangular form.  To convert from rectangular $(a+bi)$ to polar ($r \angle \theta$), use $r = \sqrt {a^2 +b^2}$ and $\theta = \arctan (b/a)$.  To convert from polar ($r \angle \theta$) to rectangular $(a+bi)$, use $a = r \cos \theta$ and $b = r \sin \theta$.

**Hint for Question $2$:**

For the numerator, convert the angles to rectangular form, and then use regular complex number operations.  (I think you have a typo in the denominator.  It should be $0.072 + j0.648$).